# Creating a multi-device app that fits on all screens

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi 10.2 and creating a multi-device app -- both for the first time.

However, I'm having issues making my UI fit on all interfaces. Let's take Android devices as an example.

I own a Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime device. Delphi 10.2 has a few preset devices, including for 4" and 5" screens. However, it seems like the screen size of my device fits none of the preset devices, being somewhere between 4" and 5" screens.

As a result, I'm always having issues with UI components behind out-of-screen or out-of-box. Here's one example.

On my IDE, here's what I see (picture is align = left; text is align = right):

[image: Delphi IDE]

But here's what I see on my device:

[image: Device]

I have many situations like this. I tried to play with aligns, margins, paddings, anchors and various layout components, but I don't quite get what is the proper way to use them and what are "hacks". I understand I could create a new preset device that fit exactly my Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime device, but it feels wrong as it ultimately means I would need to create presets for dozens, if not hundreds of devices.

What would be good starter points?

Comment: The way to make this work is to use TLayout components throughout. By carefully aligning TLayouts, and using anchors with layouts on layouts, you can achieve a "universal" configuration that works on all displays. See [] (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/FireMonkey_Layouts_Strategies)

Comment: There are no right solutions and they all depend on particular screen needs. But your primary issue is that you are aligning controls from both left and right. If the screen is not large enough controls will overlap. In above case one of the solutions would be to align text to client - it would occupy remaining space. Also you can read your screen size at run-time and resize and reposition controls if needed through code.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That's what the OP is trying to avoid. With careful use of layouts, alignment and anchors it is possible to make apps the "work" on all devices without conditional code.

Comment: @nolaspeaker I know OP is trying to avoid coding. But sometimes coding is the right approach. It depends.Sometimes you can solve everything with layouts and alignments, sometimes you can't. Too deep control hierarchies can be too slow. Like I said, it is not a simple matter and one solution does not fit all.

Answer (score 1):

Without your code it is of course quite difficult to give appropriate advice but I will try to give a few possibilities.

1. The picture and the text are two different components. Try putting them on the `TPanel` and set their `Align` property to `alLeft` and `alRight`. The `TPanel` itself will be probably `alTop` but that depends on your other elements.
2. You can ask for the width of your screen and then just scale both elements (or all present) to your needs regarding this information. Remember that there are also other possibilities to get the actual size of your monitor, this is just the first suggestion.

   ```
   MyWidth := Screen.Monitors[0].Width;
   ```
3. Ask for your device DPI. With this information you can basically calculate the perfect fit for every device.

   ```
   Result := Round(10 * Self.Monitor.PixelsPerInch / 96);
   ```

Probably the best thing to do is a combination of all three to adapt to most devices.

Comment: I just want to point out that used objects and properties are from VCL, otherwise it can be used in FMX, you just need to find the right counterpart.

Comment: There is no point in answering a question about FMX with examples from VCL. They just don't match up. And you can't expect the OP to figure it out since they've already noted that it is the first time using Delphi 10.2 and writing a Firemonkey app. Better to point them to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Layout_to_Adjust_Different_Form_Sizes_or_Orientations_%28iOS_and_Android%29